# Конвертировать BSON файл в BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

У меня есть огромный (4 Гб) файл с расширением `.bson`
Онлайн конверторы не поддерживают такой огромный размер
Подскажите, как мне его конвертнуть в `BsonDocument` (или как-то может по другому), чтобы я смог в дебаге просмотреть его структуру?

Comment: [Вот что нашел](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeToBson.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @aepot помог разобраться.

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

var audio = dirInfo.GetFiles().FirstOrDefault(fi
    => fi.Name == "audio_files.bson");

var reader = new BsonReader(File.OpenRead(audio.FullName));
var aaa = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<object>(reader);
```

Правда показывает только первый объект коллекции, но этого достаточно чтоб изучить его структуру.